# Not getting the right data to verify razorpay callback

Tags: payment-gateway, razorpay, upi

I am trying to implement razorpay apis as documented [here](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/payment-links/#using-callback-url-parameter) on my Go Server on AWS. I have configured a callback URL on razorpay with a secret. I am able to create payment link with UPI enabled and send it to my clients and the user is able to pay. I am receiving a callback from razorpay also. But, I am not getting the right parameters to verify the signature. For example: I am not getting these parameters as documented:

```
https://example-callback-url.com/?razorpay_payment_id=pay_Fc8mUeDrEKf08Y&razorpay_payment_link_id=plink_Fc8lXILABzQL7M&
```

razorpay_payment_link_reference_id=TSsd1989&
razorpay_payment_link_status=partially_paid&razorpay_signature=b0ea302006d9c3da504510c9be482a647d5196b265f5a82aeb272888dcbee70e

Instead I am getting a POST request with a body that has an object that does not have all the information that I need to validate the signature. I get the signature from the header.
How do I configure on razorpay to receive these data?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone who are facing the same confusion, this is the correct link for webhook callbacks:
https://razorpay.com/docs/webhooks/payloads/payment-links
Webhooks get the POST message that you can verify with the signature sent in the header.